# Is "Veronica" a reference to the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

During the events of *Age of Ultron*, "Veronica" is mentioned a few times.

It is eventually revealed that "Veronica" is

> The Hulkbuster suit.

Is the name "Veronica" a reference to an existing character or device in the comics or any other Marvel media?

Comment: Similar read from Movies and TV [Why was the Hulkbuster program called Veronica?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33734/why-was-the-hulkbuster-program-called-veronica)

Comment: *Spoilers* - Nitpicky detail, but "Veronica" was actually the codename for the entire Hulkbuster project - this included the AI, the vibranium cage, the suit, and the support module which followed the suit around (and ejected the spare arm during the battle). The Hulkbuster armor was only ONE component, albeit a vital one, of the Veronica program.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If so, it was entirely unintentional.

Instead, Joss Whedon claims that it's a reference to the *Archie* comics, where Veronica and Betty are the two competing love interests for Archie's attention:

> "You know, I just decided to call it Veronica because he used to be in love with a girl named Betty and Veronica is the opposite of that," Whedon said, obviously referencing Betty and Veronica, who compete for Archie Andrews' attentions in Archie.

From: ["Avengers: Age of Ultron Features an Archie Comics Reference"](http://comicbook.com/2015/04/11/avengers-age-of-ultron-features-an-archie-comics-reference/), *comicbook.com*

Comment: This is simultaneously disappointing and awesome.

Comment: you realize this means that Tony Stark reads *Archie*...

Comment: Considering Bruce says he helped create the buster, maybe he named it.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield ... If the man can figure out [thermonuclear astrophysics](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/quotes?qt=qt1686170) overnight by a little light reading, I have no doubt he is well read.

Comment: @Paulster2 Reading _Archie_ is almost anathema to being "well read".

Answer (score -2):

May not be relevant, but names from Archie comics were also used as commands before the current web came into being. WAIS, Wide Area Information System, was the web's text based precursor, and used commands like Archie, Jughead and Veronica. https://www.drblank.com/coetaci2.htm for an example of the old style web.

Comment: They weren't really "commands", they were indexing services and tools to access them (might as well call "Google" a "command")

Comment: How does this answer the question in any way?